# c++ scope and windows threads threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, scope

I have an object with a socket defined, the socket doesn't get shutdown or closed until the destructor is called. Then in a class that instantiates that object I have a thread that executes one of the methods that operates on the socket.

The only way I could get the thread to work was to have it defined like this :

```
static DWORD WINAPI writePoints(void* param)      
{
    resume
    Dac *dac = (Dac*)param;
    //...
    dac->com->write_data(dac->d,BUF_PTS,pr);
    //...
}
```

with the thread being created from the same class

```
write_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, writePoints,(void*)this, 0, &dwrite_thread);
```

But when it comes to running the code that operates on the socket, it doesnt work at all. I instead get an error saying the socket isnt a socket. But it works outside of a thread just fine. After setting a breakpoint I saw that `this` was null leading me to believe its a scoping issue.

How do I get around this error?

on an interesting side note another thread that operates on the socket works fine and doesnt seem to loose the value of `this`

the other working thread is defined as thus

```
static DWORD WINAPI ping_loop(void* param)
{
    Dac *dac = (Dac*)param;

    if (dac->com->connected())
        while (dac->com->dac_ping() == 0)
            Sleep(980);

    ExitThread(1);
    return 1;
}
```

with the main difference appearing to be that the `ping_loop` isn't passing any arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, there is a difference between `void*` and `LPVOID`, `LPVOID` seems to maintain the `this` variable

Comment: No, LPVOID is defined as `typedef void *LPVOID;`, so it is exactly the same. I guess that it worked by chance.

Comment: Well the issue was actually very strange and difficult to trace through. I have a for loop executing 1000 iterations, using void* it would consistently get through about 100 iterations then the `this` pointer I passed through a void pointer would suddenly become NULL, but changing it to LPVOID, which is used throughout the documentation, did not have this issue. If it is typedefed to the same thing, then something very strange is happening.

Comment: Probably you are using threads without proper locking and/or synchronizaton. This has non-deterministic behavior, so strange things and random crashes is the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you did not wait in Dac destructor until the thread terminated. If main function is short and simple enough, it is quite possible that your application runs out of the main funcion and destructor of Dac class has been called, but the thread created by Dac is still running.

Using **WaitForSingleObject** in destructor, wait until the thread terminated and then close the socket.

Comment: Usually saying calling TerminateThread is not a glory method to terminate a thread. Doing this can cause resource leak when a thread has aquired something but force terminated without releasing it. Anyway it looks like everything will be OK as long as to make sure to close the socket only after the thread is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling CreateThread from a member function of **Dac** class. If not that is an error by itself.

Have you verified the life time of the **Dac** object? Any data passed to **CreateThread** as **lpParameter** has to outlive the thread.

Comment: The thread is terminated in the Dac object's destructor, so I assume that means the Dac object would outlive the thread. I am calling CreateThread from a member function

Comment: Are you creating Dac on the heap using **Dac* mydac = new Dac();**